# convert to ascii or string in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, encoding

I'm reading and parsing a csv file into a dictionary. However, one of the values is this `'\xe2\x80\x94'` instead of this `'-'`. How can I convert the value to its proper format? `type('\xe2\x80\x94')` says it's a string because of the quotes but in the file it's a hyphen character.

```
import os

DATADIR = ""
DATAFILE = "beatles-diskography.csv"

def parse_file(datafile):
   data = list()
   with open(DATAFILE, 'rb') as f:
       header = f.readline().rstrip().split(',')

   for line in f:
       lst = list()
       line = line.rstrip().split(',')
       if len(line) > 7:
           line[2] = line[2] + ", " + line[3]
           del line[3]
       for i in range(len(line)):
            t = header[i],line[i]
            lst.append(t)

       data.append(dict(lst))

    return data

def test():
    # a simple test of your implemetation
    datafile = os.path.join(DATADIR, DATAFILE)
    d = parse_file(datafile)
    firstline = {'Title': 'Please Please Me', 'UK Chart Position': '1', 'Label': 'Parlophone(UK)', 'Released': '22 March 1963', 'US Chart Position': '-', 'RIAA Certification': 'Platinum', 'BPI Certification': 'Gold'}
    tenthline = {'Title': '', 'UK Chart Position': '1', 'Label': 'Parlophone(UK)', 'Released': '10 July 1964', 'US Chart Position': '-', 'RIAA Certification': '', 'BPI Certification': 'Gold'}

    #assert d[0] == firstline
    #assert d[9] == tenthline
    print d[0]
    print firstline
    #print d[9]

test()
```

Results I get are:

```
{'Title': 'Please Please Me', 'UK Chart Position': '1', 'Label':    'Parlophone(UK)', 'Released': '22 March 1963', 'US Chart Position': '\xe2\x80\x94', 'RIAA Certification': 'Platinum', 'BPI Certification': 'Gold'}
{'Title': 'Please Please Me', 'UK Chart Position': '1', 'Label': 'Parlophone(UK)', 'Released': '22 March 1963', 'US Chart Position': '-', 'RIAA Certification': 'Platinum', 'BPI Certification': 'Gold'}
```

Comment: Seems like there are some invisible characters at that place

Answer (score 1):

## The character is *em-dash*, not *hyphen*

And it is working correctly.

Only thing that is troubling you is representation of dictionaries

```
>>> print '\xe2\x80\x94'
—
>>> print {1: '\xe2\x80\x94'}
{1: '\xe2\x80\x94'}
```

To print the dict properly do this horror

```
>>> d = {1: '\xe2\x80\x94'}
>>> print repr(d).decode("unicode-escape").encode("latin-1")
{1: '—'}
```

Comment: for a dict like this d = {'Title': 'Please Please Me', 'UK Chart Position': '1', 'Label': 'Parlophone(UK)', 'Released': '22 March 1963', 'US Chart Position': '\xe2\x80\x94', 'RIAA Certification': 'Platinum', 'BPI Certification': 'Gold'} should I be dong something like d['US Chart Position'] = d['US Chart Position'].decode("unicode-escape").encode("latin-1")?

Comment: No, if you don't print entire dict, it's enough to `print d['US Chart Position']`